# I am trying to find a row with has null value as foreign key but all the columns return no rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the details of villas that have never been booked. However my query is returning no values just the column names.

Table insertion

```
Insert into villa values('V14', 'Serene Bliss', '785.95', 'T1'),
('V15', 'Serene no', '585', 'T2'),
('V16', 'Serene yesBliss', '395', 'T3'),
('V17', 'Serene wowBliss', '995', 'T4'),
('V18', 'Serene yayBliss', '700', 'T5'),
('V20', 'Lonelyislan', '200', 'T6');

Insert into Reservation values
('R321', '2020-06-12','C345'),
('R322', '2020-06-13','C745'),
('R323', '2020-06-14','C645'),
('R421', '2020-06-15','C545'),
('R521', '2020-06-16','C445');

Insert into VillaReservation values
('2020-12-01','2020-12-10','V14', 'R321'),
('2020-11-01','2020-11-10','V15', 'R322'),
('2020-10-01','2020-10-10','V16', 'R323'),
('2020-09-01','2020-09-10','V17', 'R421'),
('2020-12-08','2020-08-10','V18', 'R521'),
('2020-12-15','2020-11-10','V18', 'R521');
```

Query

```
SELECT v.villaid,
   villaname,
   villacostperday,
   villatypeid
FROM villa v,
     villareservation vr
WHERE v.villaid = vr.villaid
  AND vr.reservationid = NULL;
```

Comment: Use proper `join` syntax, its much easier to change to `left join`

Comment: You cannot compare with NULL using `=` operator - such compare will give NULL result **always** (and it is treated as FALSE). Use either `vr.reservationid <=> NULL` or `vr.reservationid IS NULL`.

Comment: I see insertion but no creation

Comment: Fixed it. Only insertion has been provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join` with a where condition `vr.reservationid is null`

```
SELECT v.villaid,
   villaname,
   villacostperday,
   villatypeid
FROM villa v
LEFT JOIN villareservation vr ON v.villaid = vr.villaid
WHERE vr.reservationid IS NULL
```

Comment: it worked! however I don't understand why my query was not working?

Comment: @AnimRahman, it's because of inner join - which only returns the match rows. Btw, if it helped don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: yes I will accept it as an answer after 12 minutes. It's not allowing me to accept right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want villas that have never booked, `NOT EXISTS` seems the most direct route:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM villa v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM villareservation vr
                  WHERE v.villaid = vr.villaid
                 )
```

;